# Python 2 to Python 3 futurize builtins str

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am converting a django application from Python 2 to Python using futurize.
I am currently futurizing future_builtins. In the following set of code in the test:

```
response = str(self.client.get(self.url))
```

I get the following error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 3261: ordinal not in range(128)` and the test fails

However, when I remove the following import:

```
from builtins import str
```

The tests pass. I tried to use decode() function but I get the same error. 
Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you want to pick a specific set of things from the reponse? for example. Outside of this I don't think it is necessarily a good idea to.

```
response = self.client.get(self.url)
if response.is_client_error() or response.is_server_error():
    # do failure
else:
    content = response.content
    # check content
```

If you are wanting to convert it to a string I wouldn't recommend it but a good compatibility is possibly.

```
response = self.client.get(self.url).__repr__() 
# or "even less recommended reason being is it will fail for eval()"
response = self.client.get(self.url).__str__()
```